# How to echo specific $categ from subpage on home page

Tags: php, echo

I have one question about echoing specific `$categ` from subpages on home page. For example, this pece of code:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $name => $value) { echo $categ[$name]; }  ?>
```

echos all categories on subpage, for example on `../library_books/`

echos:

```
category1 "library books1" -> "book1" "book2" "book3",...
category2 "library books2" -> "book1" "book2" "book3",...
category3 "library books3" -> "book1" "book2" "book3",...
```

How can I echo for example category2 `library books2` with only 1 subcategory for example: `book2` on home page `domain.com`

Thanks

Comment: I have not understood your question or your example, please try to be more clear.

Comment: Hi, I want to echo category2 from subpage ../library_books/ on home page with subcategories that I choose (example: exclude book1 and book3 but include book2.